# Python Selenium options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/User Data") messed my chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I used the below lines of code, to run Chrome with Selenium with cookies pre accepted.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User
Data")  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
 driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But the add_argument messed up my chrome, logged out from all accounts, is there a way to revert my chrome settings to the previous ones? And how to use this code without this happening again?

Comment: No, you are logged out now. You have to re-login. I trust you still remember the password.

Comment: Create a custom profile in Chrome and use that one for testing... you can keep user-data-dir the same and add the profile-directory argument with the profile name that you created.   I'm not sure how the posted code could have affected your default account though.  Did you execute JS to clear cookies?